# TV show about a detective forced to partner with a cyborg

Tags: story-identification, tv, cyborg

Around 2000, there was a TV Show on our national TV named "Shadow of Dreams". It was about the a detective in the future who forced to accept a cyborg as a partner.

The main arc story of the show was that nobody knows who had made the cyborg. It was the most advanced cyborg at the time and they were searching for the maker.

Please help find the real name of the show.

Comment: Your national TV being which country? What was “Shadow of Dreams” the title of exactly? Are you looking for a series or a single episode?

Comment: Holmes & Yoyo seems to fit the description.              http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeJd7j-Rhtg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a TV show produced in Canada, [Total Recall 2070](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_2070), that seems to fit the bill.